# html dd tag ploblem

Tags: html

i am using dd tag 
but ie / firefox show diffrent

1.ie
nomal view : no padding , no margin
2.firefix
strange view : some padding or some margin

html source code is

dd tag align is left , no margin , padding

html source

```
<STYLE>
.sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0 0 0 0 ; padding: 0 0 0 0; width: 100%; float:left; }
.sortable li { float:left; width:100%; }
.sortable li dd { 
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    border:thin inset;  
}
.sortable #topmenu dd { background-color:#e7e7e7;}
.sortable li .seq {width:4%;}
.sortable li .mdp {width:11%;}
.sortable li .korname {width:10%;}
.sortable li .chrCd {width:10%;}
.sortable li .name {width:30%;}
.sortable li .direct {width:18%;}
.sortable li .result {width:7%;}
.liList { 
    font-family: 굴림,arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 11pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:17px;
    text-align:center;      
}       
</STYLE>
<div>
<ul class="sortable">
    <li class="liList" id="topmenu">
        <dd class="seq"><b>번호</b></dd>
        <dd class="mdp"><b>MDP구분</b></dd>
        <dd class="korname"><b>학습단계</b></dd>
        <dd class="chrCd"><b>강좌코드</b></dd>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable"> 
    <li class="liList">
            <dd class="seq" id="re">5</dd>
            <dd class="mdp">MDP</dd>
            <dd class="korname">특강</dd>
            <dd class="chrCd" id="chrCd_1">12131</dd>
    </li>   
    <li class="liList">
            <dd class="seq" id="re">4</dd>
            <dd class="mdp">MDP</dd>
            <dd class="korname">문제풀이</dd>
            <dd class="chrCd" id="chrCd_2">12227</dd>
    </li>   
    <li class="liList">
            <dd class="seq" id="re">3</dd>
            <dd class="mdp">MDP</dd>
            <dd class="korname">특강</dd>
            <dd class="chrCd" id="chrCd_3">12215</dd>
    </li>   
    <li class="liList">
            <dd class="seq" id="re">2</dd>
            <dd class="mdp">MDP</dd>
            <dd class="korname">기본완성</dd>
            <dd class="chrCd" id="chrCd_4">12171</dd>
    </li>   
    <li class="liList">
            <dd class="seq" id="re">1</dd>
            <dd class="mdp">MDP</dd>
            <dd class="korname">기본완성</dd>
            <dd class="chrCd" id="chrCd_5">12147</dd>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

why diffrent show??

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org). A list with one item rarely makes sense. A li cannot be the parent node of a dd. A dd without a dt makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DD tag can only appear in a DL, and should be accompanied by a DT.  Looks to me like you should be using a UL and LIs like this:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li class="liList" id="topmenu">
        <ul>
          <li class="seq"><b>번호</b></li>
          <li class="mdp"><b>MDP구분</b></li>
          <li class="korname"><b>학습단계</b></li>
          <li class="chrCd"><b>강좌코드</b></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found solution , dd parent dt tag li>dd ->> dl > dt > dd 
thank you for your answers